# Need to save(hold) value without pressing Enter key in dynamically change text filed using OracleADF

Tags: java-8, oracle-adf

`I have a dropdown and text field
When selecting the dropdown,a value comes to that text field
( without selecting the dropdown also we can type value in this text field)
When we type value,that value is saved when we back using valueChangeListner.
But if the text field value from dropdown,it doesn’t save.
Issue is not entering Enter key.
S**elect dropdown value-> come value to the text field-> click enter button using keyboard** (this will save)
**Select dropdown value-> come value to the text field-> not click enter button** (this won’t save)
I want to save the value eventhough I don’t press enter
this is my text field code.

`<af:inputText label="text area" id=12 rows=5

value="#{pageFlowScope.item1}"

valueChangeListner="#{pageFlowScope.ValueChanged}"

autoSubmit="true">

</af:inputText>`

I want to save/hold value eventhough not pressing the enter key.`

Comment: Did you try with the attribute immediate="true" ?

Comment: Which exact JDev version do you use? Show us the code how the text field is set from the drop-down, please.